# Having trouble having two methods inside another

Tags: c#, methods, compiler-errors

I've been having trouble with inserting two methods inside of a larger one. I have been told by another forum that c# 8 supports this, but even the latest version of my compiler only supports up to version 5. does anyone know how to help? I'm a beginner and would much appreciate it. let me know if i can provide more information.

the program is just a test to a text based game, the player puts their name in and then they get to collect coins, I've run coincheck() at the end of each outcome in order to make it repeatable but the balance variable would reset every time, i finally found a possible fix by putting both the methods into main but my compiler doesn't seem to like that.

```
using System;

// namespace declaration 
namespace test {

    // Class declaration 
    class Geeks {


        // Main Method 
        static void Main()
        {

            int balance = 0;

            static void namecheck()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");


                string name;
                name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}", name);
                coincheck();
            }

            static void coincheck()
            {
                string coininp;

                Console.WriteLine("Type 'collect' to pick up a coin and 'wallet' to check your wallet.");
                coininp = Console.ReadLine();
                if (coininp == "collect")
                {
                    balance = balance + 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("you found a coin!");
                    coincheck();
                }
                if (coininp == "wallet")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("you have {0} coins in your wallet", balance);
                    coincheck();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                    coincheck();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If your compiler doesn’t support it then it doesn’t. In general it’s not very common to have methods inside methods, it’s for very specific situations. Why not have them outside like normally?

Comment: 1) Why are you trying to do that? It's really not neccesary. 2) Why are you compiling with `csc` instead of using `msbuild` or `dotnet`? 3) Why not just upgrade your compiler?

Answer (score 3):

[Local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#local-functions) are supported only in C# version 7 or later. It simply is impossible in earlier versions.

The closest you can come is with anonymous methods, which *are* allowed to exist inside another method. For example:

```cs
void M1()
{
    Action M2 = () => Console.WriteLine("M2");

    // Now you can invoke the delegate representing your anonymous method
    // as if it were a nested method:
    M2();
}
```

That can sometimes be appropriate, often for the same reason local functions are: to isolate code that is strictly useful only in the local context. But I don't recommend it for anything but the simplest scenarios.

In your example, where the method bodies are large, I would just put those methods outside as regular methods in the class. If you really must have them as local functions, then you need to upgrade to C# 7 or later.